# iOS - writeToFile from NSData completion handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am getting bytes of a file from a webservice, my goal is to get these bytes, put them into NSData and then write into a file, once the writeToFile is 100% complete, I would then display the file (its a PDF, can be up to 6 pages) in QLPreviewController.

I am able to get the bytes from the webservice and put them into NSData like so:

```
NSArray *byteArray = [dataSource.areaData GetPDFFileData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",encodedUrlStr]];

        NSData *data;

        for (NSDictionary *dict in byteArray) {
            NSString *base64 = dict[@"data"];
            data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64 options:0];
        }
```

Now I am trying to write the file like so:

```
if (data)
        {
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,PDFFile];

            [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

        }
```

Now what I am trying to do is have some sort of completion handler so nothing else happens until the file is completely written. What would be the best way to do this?

I am also starting to look into NSFileHandle, would that be a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use NSFilePresenter to monitor for changes to the file
and use a NSFileCoordinator to write to it

in mock code:

```
NSFilePresenter *p = [NSFilePresenter presenterWithFile:f];
[p signupForChangeNotificationsOrSetDelegateOrWhatever....];

//write 
NSFileCoordinator *c = [NSFileCoordinator coordinatorWithPresenter:p];
[c coordinate writeData....]

... called back by p cause we changed
```

Comment: What is FVEvents?

Comment: sorry that was FSEvents. typo. BUT it isnt ideal anyway - you want a NSFileCoordinator

Comment: Can you provide an example of NSFileCoordinator?

Comment: update my code a bit. this mock is from reading the api. I used FSEvents in a dark past. This should get you started though.

Comment: I keep getting this error and yes I do have Foundation imported `Use of undeclared identifier 'NSFilePresenter'`

Comment: what api level are you targeting? is it even in your sdk? :) please show some code

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry about completion if this runs in main queue it's serial , but it's better to save in background queue and read content to verify and present in main Queue

```
  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        print("This is run on the background queue")

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
        {
            NSLog(@"not exists");

            NSData *fileContents = [@"" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath
                                                    contents:fileContents
                                                  attributes:nil];

        }
        else
        {
             NSLog(@"exists");

        }


        NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
        [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];


        NSString*strTowrite=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ || %@ --- %@ \r\n",dt,acion,name];

        [myHandle writeabilityHandler];

        [myHandle writeData:[strTowrite dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NSString*content=[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                            error:&error];
         if(content)
        {


            NSLog(@"content is : %@ Err : %@",content,error);

            // [self sendfile];


        }
        else
        {

            NSLog(@"Failed to store the file. Error = %@", error);

        }
     }
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand this line:

Comment: NSString*strTowrite=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ || %@ --- %@ \r\n",dt,acion,name]; what is dt....what is action....what is name? What would they be in my case

Comment: it's any thing u want to save i mean any string

Comment: I feel this is hacky if it even works.. well it works because IO will be serialized, so writing happens before reading here but ..... dont know.. seems overhead. imagine you write/copy/move 200MB. Do you really want to read it all back :D

Comment: @Daij-Djan , sure don't want to read it back , I wrote it like this as verification that write step occurred successfully , also i assumed that write process won't be that large 200 MB is a horrible size to write in a mobile application